# How can we divide different actions to be done by different loads in a thread group of a Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a requirement of load testing with 100 users, and a ramp-up period of 500.so that in every 5 sec, 1 user will login.i have some actions to be done in the application.lets say there are 50 scenarios. so out of 100 users, each of 2 should do one scenario.

```
how can i set 2 users should do one scenario out of 50 scenarios in a thread group.
```

Can anyone help me..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

First, JMeter does not have the concept of users, but VUsers which are Java threads instantiated by a TG. If the 50 scenarios are unique and need to be executed simultaneously, the suggestion is to create 50 distinct TG with 2 Vusers each.